# Stop Wrapping From Adding Space on New Line (XSL-FO)

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using the following to allow for text to wrap within a cell (fop-1.0).

```
fo:table-cell wrap-option="wrap" keep-together.within-column="always"
```

This is working but when the text is wrapped to the next line, a space is added at the beginning of the text on each subsequent line. I'd like the text to all start in the same position.

For example currently:

```
Line one begins here.....
 Line two begins here.....
 Line three begins here.....
```

For example would prefer:

```
Line one begins here.....
Line two begins here.....
Line three begins here.....
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rita

Comment: Would you kindly add your described input XML?

Comment: In "normal" situations, spaces at the beginning of a line are discarded; are you using `white-space-treatment="preserve"` somewhere?

Comment: The default for `wrap-option` is `wrap`, so setting it to its default value is useful only if the inherited value is `no-wrap`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#wrap-option

Comment: Oh my goodness! Yes, I was using white-space-treatment="preserve" in my fo:block. Once I removed that, the space at the beginning of the subsequent lines was removed.

Thank you and thanks to all for your responses.

Comment: Can i eliminate the white spaces without removing `white-space-treatment="preserve" `. Because i need that attribute to be set as i have tab spaces in my text which i want to preserve